# How to add an extra prop based on child prop using React.cloneElement()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add an extra prop to the first child that has the prop type `scan` so i can enable autofocus on the first scan component that is rendered?

Here is what i have so far:

```
import React, { cloneElement } from 'react;

export default function Form({ children }) {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

  ...
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {children.map((child, i) => {
        if (child.props.config.type === "scan" && !focus) {
          cloneElement(child, { focus: true });
          return setFocus(true);
        }
        return cloneElement(child, { focus: false });
      })}
    </form>
  );

});
```

any suggestions would be great, thanks

Comment: Where does `setFocus` come from? Do you want to focus via reference or via state? Please make a producible example so it will be clear what you trying to achieve. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash apologies, i have now added more context to the example, thanks

Comment: can you do something like if index === 0, then setfocus to true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are problematic in your code.

- you return the value of `setFocus` instead of `cloneElement` from map function
- you are using `setFocus` directly in render.

If you must know whether there is a child with scan prop, make use of useRef

```
export default function Form({ children }) {
  const focus = useRef(false);

  ...
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {children.map((child, i) => {
        if (child.props.config.type === "scan" && !focus.current) {
          focus.current = true;
          return cloneElement(child, { focus: true });

        }
        return cloneElement(child, { focus: false });
      })}
    </form>
  );

});
```